# Storing pair of ints on the list

Tags: c#, list, integer

How can I store pairs of integers in a List?
I know I could make a class for them like:

```
class Pair  
{
    int i1,i2;
}
```

But if I do that I'm not able to use the `Contains` function to check if a given pair is in the list. How can I do that so I can easily store integers in a List and check if a pair of integers already exists? I cannot use table because it is not known how many pairs there will be.

**EDIT:**
Forgot to add:
In my program pairs (x, y) and (y, x) are to be treated as equals.

**EDIT:**
(x,y) and (y,x) are equals while checking if `Point` is in the list, but `x` and `y` can not be swapped because `x` and `y` represent a connection between two points (integer is id of point, and no I can't use any reference etc...). When I'm checking if `List` contains a connection it is not important if it is (x,y) or (y,x) but later I would need that information.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4.0, you could use the `Tuple` class as in

```
var tuple = new Tuple<int, int>(17, 42);
var otherTuple = Tuple.Create(17, 42);
```

and

```
var list = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
```

Note that if you go the route of using `Tuple<int, int>` then you will need to create a custom implementation of `IEqualityComparer<Tuple<TFirst, TSecond>>` to reflect your equality rules that `(x, y)` be considered equal to `(y, x)`. You will then have to pass an instance of this comparer to `List<T>.Contains(T, IEqualityComparer<T>)` (here `T` is `Tuple<int, int>` for you).

```
class TupleAsUnorderedPairComparer : IEqualityComparer<Tuple<TFirst, TSecond>> {
    public bool Equals(Tuple<TFirst, TSecond> x, Tuple<TFirst, TSecond> y) {
        if(Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) {
            return true;
        }
        if(x == null || y == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return x.Item1 == y.Item1 && x.Item2 == y.Item2 ||
               x.Item1 == y.Item2 && x.Item2 == y.Item1;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Tuple<TFirst, TSecond> x) {
        if(x == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return x.Item1.GetHashCode() ^ x.Item2.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if you can't or don't want to use `Tuple` then you will need to implement an `IEqualityComparer<Pair>` for your `Pair` class or override `Object.Equals` and `Object.GetHashCode`.

```
class Pair {
    public int First { get; private set; }
    public int Second { get; private set; }
    public Pair(int first, int second) {
        this.First = first;
        this.Second = second;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        if(Object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) {
            return true;
        }
        Pair instance = obj as Pair;
        if(instance == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return this.First == instance.First && this.Second == instance.Second ||
               this.First == instance.Second && this.Second == instance.First;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return this.First.GetHashCode() ^ this.Second.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

and

```
class PairEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Pair> {
    // details elided 
}
```

If you use

```
list.Contains(pair);
```

then it will use `Equals` and `GetHashCode` but if you use

```
list.Contains(pair, new PairEqualityComparer);
```

then it will use `PairEqualityComparer.Equals` and `PairEqualityComparer.GetHashCode`. Note that these *could* be different than your implementations of `Object.Equals` and `Object.GetHashCode`.

**Finally, if testing for containment is something that you'll be doing often then a `List` is not your best bet; you should use a class designed for that purpose like a `HashSet`.**

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect your need for `(x, y)` to be considered equal to `(y, x)`.

Answer (score 2):

The class is your best bet. If you're dead set on using the `Contains` method, you'll have to implement the `IComparable` interface in your Pair class. This will allow you to establish what "equality" means for this pair of integers.

The simplest way would be to create the class as you have and then create and extension method on the `List<T>` object.

```
public static bool ContainsIntegers(this List<Pair> targetList, Pair comparer) {
    foreach(Pair pair in targetList)
    {
        if(pair.i1 == comparer.i1 && pair.i2 == comparer.i2) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this would be to use a `List<ulong>`, populating it by putting the largest number in the upper 32 bits and the other number in the lower 32 bits:

```
ulong MakeEntry(int i1, int i2)
{
    ulong hi = (ulong)Math.Max(i1, i2);
    ulong lo = (ulong)Math.Min(i1, i2);
    return (hi << 32) | lo;
}

List<ulong> items = new List<ulong>();

void DoSomething()
{
    // get numbers i1 and i2
    // and add to the list
    items.Add(MakeEntry(i1, i2));

    // test to see if the pair is in the list
    if (items.Contains(MakeEntry(i1, i2)))
    {
        // do whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work because of the requirement that `(x, y)` be treated as equal to `(y, x)`. That is, the OP is using _unordered_ pairs as opposed to _ordered_ pairs.

Comment: @Jason:  Huh?  The min/max in the `MakeEntry` method ensures that (x, y) and (y, x) are treated identically.  The largest one is always in the high-order bits.

Comment: Whereas this solution will treat (x,y) as equal to (y,x), it does so by swapping the two values. It's not clear to me whether the OP wants i1 and i2 to be individually accessible. If so, this solution would not work.

Answer (score -1):

Make a list of vector2's instead.
Treat that list as a pair of ints.

Hacky? Maybe, but much simpler than all of that above really.

Comment: `Vector2` is a pair of `float`s, not a pair of `int`s. Floats have decimal places, and because of floating-point precision, it can be challenging to get "correct" answers when performing arithmetic. You would almost certainly have to round, which is just another step. Comparing these numbers (as the OP stated they need to do) would also be a lot more complicated because floats aren't exact. This also makes displaying these numbers in string format more complicated for the same reasons. Ultimately the simpler solution would just be to use a tuple as stated in the accepted answer.

Comment: This solution also doesn't satisfy the requirement stated in the OP's edits stating that `(x,y)` should be treated as equivalent to `(y,x)`.